# How does yum check for required library on install (dependency problem)

Tags: rpm, yum

I'm running into an issue with an RPM build with rpmbuild.

I used a SRPM to build a custom version of PHP but when I try to install this RPM yum gives the following error on other servers than the server compiled on:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php70-cli-7.0.33-1.el6.x86_64 (local)
           Requires: libiconv.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: php70-common-7.0.33-1.el6.x86_64 (local)
           Requires: libiconv.so.2()(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Build server:

```
[root@server rpmbuild]# file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2: symbolic link to `libiconv.so.2.6.0'
```

Install server:

```
[root@otherserver ~]# file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2: symbolic link to `libiconv.so.2.6.0'
```

Can someone explain to me why yum couldn't find it? Or push me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the RPM database, as far as `rpm` and `yum` are concerned, it didn't happen. Since `/usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2` is in `/usr/local`, and Fedora [explicitly says not to put things there](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_Files_or_Directories_under_.2Fsrv.2C_.2Fusr.2Flocal.2C_or_.2Fhome.2F.24USER), I'm assuming it wasn't installed by an RPM.

One way to check would be `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2` - I'm assuming it will say it's not provided by any package.

You need to install an RPM that provides it (a quick search reveals [a mirror here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/forensics-x86_64/libiconv-1.15-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)) on *both* the build and target machines. Then rebuild the RPM (bumping the release number!).